How to set X-Frame-Options and/or Content-Security-Policy to specific URI with Nginx?
I have this server running on a Docker Container with Nginx. The Nginx follows the structure of this repo: h5bp/server-configs-nginx.
I need the page mywebsite.com/singup to be allowed in 'iframe's. When trying to do so a error message is displayed in the developer console: "Refused to display 'https://mywebsite.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
This signup page is a ReactJS app.
So far I've tried updating the nginx.conf file with:
server {
  location /signup {
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
  }
}

server {
  location ~/signup {
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
  }
}

server {
  location ~* /signup {
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
  }
}

server {
  location /signup {
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *" always;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
  }
}

So far, nothing managed to allow the page to be framed. Is the problem really with Nginx or with the ReactJS App?
